# TypeError: 'GKVariable' object is not callable

Tags: python, gekko

I get an error when running the following code:

```py
from gekko import GEKKO
m = GEKKO()
U1 = m.Param()
A1 = m.Param()
T2 = m.Var()
T1 = m.Var()
V1 = m.Var()
m.Equation(V1() == U1*A1*(T2-T1))
m.solve()
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\johnh\Desktop\test.py", line 8, in <module>
    m.Equation(V1() == U1*A1*(T2-T1))
TypeError: 'GKVariable' object is not callable
```

How can I solve this error?

Comment: Hi there and welcome to SO. Please edit your question some code that you ran to generate this exception. A single line of traceback is insufficient for anyone to debug.

Answer (score 0):

The error is with `V1()`. Either leave out the parenthesis to make it just `V1` or else add the time derivative with `V1.dt()`. If this is an energy balance, you may want to make `V1` a function of temperature such as `m*cp*T1.dt()` with the mass `m` and heat capacity `cp`.

Here is a dynamic simulation:

```py
from gekko import GEKKO
m = GEKKO()
m.time = [0,1,2,3,4,5]
U1 = m.Param(1)
A1 = m.Param(1)
T2 = m.Param(1.1)
T1 = m.Param(1)
V1 = m.Var(0)
m.Equation(V1.dt() == U1*A1*(T2-T1))
m.options.IMODE = 4 
m.solve()
print(V1.value)
```

This produces the solution `V1 = [0,0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4,0.5]`